# Handle cycle dependancy in custom deserialization with Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

In my Java project, using Hibernate, I have two beans <sup><sub>(only relevant attributes are shown here)</sub></sup>:

```
public class Project {
    private int projectId;
    private String property1; 
    // ...

    @JsonSerialize(using=MyOwnSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using=MyOwnDeserializer.class)
    private List<ProjectItem> items;
}

public class ProjectItem {
    private String code;
    private String value;
    private String stuff;
    private Project project;
}
```

As you can see, a project has a list of items and each item is bound to one project. For simplicity in my front-end application, I serialize the list by myself to get a JSON like this, to avoid iteration over the whole list when I want to access to one code:

```
{ "projectId": 12345,
  "property1": "foo",
  "items": {"code1": {"value": "foo", "stuff": "bar"}, 
            "code2": {"value": "baz", "stuff": "abc"}, 
             ...
           }
}
```

What I want is to set back the `Project` reference at the deserialization (JSON to POJO). What I have done for the moment is:

```
// From MyOwnDeserializer
public List<ProjectItem> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
         throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();

    // Read property  
    Iterator<String> it = node.fieldNames();

    ArrayList<ProjectItem> lst = new ArrayList<ProjectItem>();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        String code = it.next();
        JsonNode subnode = node.findValue(code);

        ProjectItem obj = new ProjectItem();
        obj.setCode(code);
        obj.setValue(getStringOrNull(subnode, "value")); // own function which returns
        // ...                                           // null or a String, nothing special

        // So far, I can't call setProject() (I don't have any 
        // reference to the parent), so project is still null. 
        lst.add(obj);
    }

    return lst; 
}
```

Now, what I am looking for is: **How can I translate the project reference, which is the parent object of the item, in the deserialization?**. I can put the projectId in my JSON if needed.

I looked in the `ctxt` object via the debugger, I can see my `Project` object in the `_objectIds` HashMap but I can't really access to it...

Comment: Have you looked at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences ?